# Exploding features based on numerical field in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a set of data as polygons, each with a Number field with value X. Is there then a way to copy this into X number of polys at the same location? (ideally points distributed across the poly but that's a bonus).

In QGIS I have tried Random Points, but this doesn't inherit attributes, and Join Attributes by Location is useless if the parent polys overlap.

The reason behind this is for collating data easily with the GroupStats plugin.

Comment: I think it is answered at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25709/splitting-shapefile-into-separate-shapefiles-for-each-feature-using-qgis-gdal-sa

Comment: I looked at that and have tried split by attribute, but it's not what I require. I need each feature copied a number of times equal to a field value, not split into parts.

Comment: Because the same problem, i digged into R to get a solution. I'm sure this can be done with Python as well, but I new R beforehand. This worked for me with modifications http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/108139/8202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to do with a small python script.
You can paste the following snippet to the python console.
To initialize the `layer` variable you can select it in the TOC and run `layer = iface.activeLayer()` befor running the code.

```
layer.startEditing()
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    # Create X-1 new features since we already have the original
    for i in range(f['X']-1):
        layer.addFeature(f)
layer.commitChanges()
```

Or to write it to another layer (make sure it has the same attributes and geometry type!):

```
ltarget.startEditing()
for f in lsource.getFeatures():
    for i in range(f['X']):
        ltarget.addFeature(f)
ltarget.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Wow, nice and short. But wouldn't it be better to create a new layer instead of altering the original data. Things can always go wrong ...

Comment: You are right of course, it's a minimal change. I tried to keep the manual steps (adding another layer) to a minimum.