# Creating empty copy of active layer in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, copy

I'm trying to create an empty copy of a certain layer, so no objects only tablestructure, crs etc.

```
from qgis.utils import *
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
print layer.name()                           
provider = layer.dataProvider()
print provider.fields()[0].name()
writer1 = QgsVectorFileWriter("d:/temp/qgis/test3.shp", 
                              "CP1250", 
                              provider.fields(), 
                              provider.geometryType(), 
                              provider.crs(), 
                              "ESRI Shapefile")
```

When I open the created file (test3) there is no tablestructure, crs. etc.

Running the script the second time with test3 still open, it works.

Obviously I miss something .

[image]

---

An other good working solution I found later:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/156096/67332/

it loads it into a memory layer.

Comment: I don't understand your "it works" because your code doesn't work in that way for me. May you put an image of this behavior?

Comment: @PolyGeo No its not a duplicate question. The other question is about memory layers. This one is not. I gave that link to the other question to let others users know that I found also another solution with another technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested in the QGIS Console with QGis 2.14.15 and run into the same issue.

The fix is simple, you just missed one step. You need to reset the Variable `writer1`.

I did it with `writer1 = None` which created the file as expected

Comment: It only copy field names but not  table structure (records).

Comment: @xunilk jeah but thats what op is after or did I miss something?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. working fine now. Putting writer1 = None at the end.

Comment: @JAS the best way for saying *thanks* here is accepting the answer that you reputed as the most useful for solving your issue.

Comment: @xunilk Sorry about the misunderstanding about tablestructure, I meant the fieldnames and their types.

Comment: Another good working resolution I found later: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/156096/67332/

it loads it into a memory layer.