# Repeating points by field using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a point layer in ArcGIS that has a field named "Population" that stores an integer value for every point in the layer.

I want to create N points in the exact place of the feature that has N as value in the population "field". I mean, if a point has in the population field 16, I need to create 15 more points in that exact lat long (1+15 so that there are 16 in total) of that point.

Comment: Are you familiar with python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [explode features based on numerical field](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155961/explode-features-based-on-numerical-field)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't familiar with python.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: This question may have had a [tag:qgis] tag (which I am removing) but asks only about ArcGIS in its body, and so I do not think it is a duplicate of the earlier QGIS Q&A.

Comment: you can find the information on how to achieve this using python fairly easily with a few google searches. I'd suggest reading about 'search cursors' and 'insert cursors' as well as reading and writing the geometry of features from the 'shape' field.

Comment: You could do it in Excel using the attributes from your layer with the x and y fields calculated. Once you have manipulated the data in excel, you can then create the new layer using the excel table by using "Add XY Data"

Comment: That is great I did by Excel. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments the asker ended up using Excel as suggested by @TsvGis:

> You could do it in Excel using the attributes from your layer with the
>   x and y fields calculated. Once you have manipulated the data in
>   excel, you can then create the new layer using the excel table by
>   using "Add XY Data"

Personally, I would do this using ArcPy cursors, but using ModelBuilder could provide a more cumbersome alternative (iterators, Select, Copy, Append).

The principle is to iterate through the points and use the population field value to decide how many times to copy each.