# Create random points within polygons of a spatial data frame in R

Tags: r

I want to create random points within polygons that are stored in a spatial data frame in R.

I tried to use the `csr` function of the `splancs` package, and the `spsample` of the `sp` package without success. I typed the following code:

```
Csr(Greece.map[1, ], 12)
```

And received:

> Error in storage.mode(poly) <- "double" no method for coercing this s4
>   class to a vector

And `sample(Greece.map[1, ], n=12, random)` receiving the following error:

> Error in sample.Spatial(as(x, "Spatial"), n_tot * (1 + its * 0.1),
>   type = type, : object random not found.

Comment: see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108046/how-to-create-randomly-points-within-polygons-for-each-row-of-a-dataframe-matchi

Comment: If using sf then consider https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_sample.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First we don't know what `Greece.map` is, so please try and use commonly available data for examples. I'll use the `columbus` spatial polygons obtained from `library(spdep)` and `example(columbus)`.

Second, the syntax for `sample` is wrong:

```
sample(Greece.map[1, ], n=12, random)
```

is wrong on two counts: it should probably be `spsample`, and `random` is a character string, not a bare word like that. For me:

```
> spsample(columbus,n=12,"random")
SpatialPoints:
              x        y
 [1,]  9.633657 12.18918
 [2,]  7.920523 11.79233
 [3,]  9.069013 12.94617
 [4,]  8.868344 12.45160
 [5,]  7.310185 11.46700
```

works perfectly, generating 12 points in the Columbus region.